# Child Components have no props.theme for Styled Components with React Router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, styled-components

```
import {theme} from "./themes";

const App = () => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <ErrorBoundary showError>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <switch>
            <Route path="/page1" exact component={Page} />
            <Route path="/notfound" component={NotFound} />
          </switch>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  </ThemeProvider>
export default hot(module)(App);
```

Now in my Page Component my props do not include theme i.e props.theme is undefined

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

My Page component has the reducer,location,match props but no theme

Answer (score 5):

As written in the [docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced):

> In the render tree **all styled-components** will have access to the provided theme

and **only** them!

This means that your 'normal' components won't get the theme-object in their props. It took me sometime to get that. They could have written it a bit better in the docs.

The Themeprovider uses the [react-context api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), which means everything you put in there will be avaiable under this.context.yourVaribaleName and not in the props these are two different things.
*(for further and right usage see the offical react doc for the context api (previous link))*

So in the Page Component just you do:

```
const Button = styled.button`
    font-size: 1em;
    color: ${props => props.theme.main};
    border: 2px solid ${props => props.theme.main};
`;

class Page extends React.Component {
    render(){
     return(<Button>Normal</Button>);
    }
}
```

(the props.theme in the styled component does not mean that the components that you will use the styled-component in, also has this in its props)

**OR**

If you want your theme object outside of a styled component, in a 'normal' components props you have to use the withTheme HOC. See [docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#getting-the-theme-without-styled-components). *(as mentioned in a [former answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52732385/2529666))*

Answer (score 2):

To consume the theme at the component level and not inside styling, you need to use the `withTheme` higher order component. https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#withtheme